# computing efficiency in R: conditional or new vector assignment?

Tags: r

I have a function that performs some math (simplified):

```
gam<-function(){
   x<-aa
   ser<-1/x
   gamln<<-x*aa*ser
}
```

The function gets called in other functions when computing gamln is required:

```
gser<-function(){
    gammap()
    print(gamln)
    #further computing using 'gamln'...
}
```

I need to assign space for the `gamln` vector within the `gser()` function, but for this model I've been worried about computational efficiency. I thought that a conditional to check for the existence of the vector could be helpful, but I have no idea which would be more 'effort':

```
if (!exists("gamln"){
   gamln<-vector(mode="numeric",length=1)
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself? You could use tic() and toc() functions for this purpose.

Comment: You say you thought it could be useful to check for the existence of the vector, but you "have no idea which would be more effort." I don't understand what "which" means here. What is the other option you're comparing to?

Comment: The 'which' is either 1) allocating the vector each time it's needed or 2) checking to see if it already exists before creating it. I'll look into tic() and toc()